# How to make a filename dynamic when extracting a table from BigQuery to a GCS Bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I am new to Stack Overflow, and this is my first post.

I am also new to GCP, and I am writing a Python script (Airflow DAG) to extract a table from BigQuery to a GCS Bucket using the following:

```
project = "bigquery-public-data"
dataset_id = "samples"
table_id = "my_dataset"

destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "mydataset.csv")
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location="US",
)  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

print(
    "Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri)
)
```

The issue I have is, how do I makw my filename dynamic?

I am wanting my filename to look something like this: `my_file_mmddyyyy.csv`.

How do I go about doing this, as I am really not sure what to do.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

I have tried looking at the GCP documentation, but I have not had much looking finding an answer to what I am wanting to achieve.

Comment: Why are you using airflow to do that? Do you need orchestration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following operator with `Airflow` : `BigQueryToGCSOperator` :

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToGCSOperator

date_str = ...

BigQueryToGCSOperator(
        task_id="task_id",
        source_project_dataset_table="{my_project}:{my_dataset}.{my_table}",
        export_format='CSV',
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=[
            f"gs://my_bucket/my_folder/my_file_{date_str}"
        ],
        field_delimiter=','
    )
```

- `source_project_dataset_table` is the `BigQuery` source table
- `destination_cloud_storage_uris` is the destination file name in the destination bucket, you can generate your file name as needed dynamically.